# Equalize over slope and flat surface velocity in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've posted a similar question but it is not exactly the same problem so here I go.

I'm not using physics in my project, so every force it's calculated and applied by me. The point is that the character covers the same area in the same time regardless the inclination of the surface is running on.

Being applied the same movement into the CharacterController.Move() function, the velocity of the controller increases exponentially to try to move along the same surface than being in a flat area.

For example. If a prints the movemement calculated that will be applied in the "Move()" function, it is a normalize one, being (0,0,1) in perpendicular and (0.7,0,0.7) in diagonal. However, if I retrieve the velocity via CharacterController.velocity.magnitude I get a different one, being 8 on flat surface and 11.47 in a 45º slope.

I've made a formula to calculate what is the value that should be retrieved with that "velocity.magnitude" function.

```
groundAngle = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Round(Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, transform.forward)) - 90);

groundMovementMagnitude = characterController.velocity.magnitude;

slopeMovementIdeal = ((((groundAngle/2) - groundAngle) + 100) * (groundMovementMagnitude / 100));
```

With this formula, I get in fact a value of "8" in a flat surface and instead of "11.47", the value of the velocity retrieved in a 45º inclination slope is "6.4"

Nevertheless, this value is simply informative, because the velocity of the character controller can not be set. Instead of that, I need a way to modify the movement Vector3 that will be used to trigger the movement, so, instead of moving (0,0,1) on a slope, or (0.7,0,0.7) in diagonal on a slope, apply a reducer to deduct this Vector3 depending on the angle of the slope.

Comment: Are you using Unitys build in CharacterController or making your own? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html

Comment: I'm using Unity's CharacterController. I think I just need a formula that by using the ground angle apply a modificator to the movement vector.

Answer (score 0):

What I've finally done is using the velocity magnitude to calculate the difference between on flat movement and on slope. Then, I just converted that value into a normalized vector and deduct it to the characters movement.

```
        float minMovement = 0.01f;
        float difference = 0.0f;
        float x = 0.0f;
        float z = 0.0f;

        if (OnSlope() && characterController.velocity.magnitude - moveSpeed > minMovement) {
            difference = characterController.velocity.magnitude - moveSpeed;
            //Diagonal
            if ((movement.x > minMovement || movement.x < -minMovement) && (movement.z > minMovement || movement.z < -minMovement)) {
                x = z = (difference / 2) / characterController.velocity.magnitude;

                if (movement.x < 0)
                    x *= -1;
                if (movement.z < 0)
                    z *= -1;
            }
            //Perpendicular
            else {
                if (movement.x > minMovement || movement.x < -minMovement) {
                    x = difference / moveSpeed;
                    if (movement.x < 0)
                        x *= -1;
                }
                if (movement.z > minMovement || movement.z < -minMovement) {
                    z = difference / moveSpeed;
                    if (movement.x < 0)
                        z *= -1;
                }
            }
            movement.x -= x;
            movement.z -= z;
        }
```

It is working fine.